# How to use multiple datasets in order to measure the performance of a learning system?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, hyperparameter

I’m working on a project where I need to test a machine learning system which has a lot of hyper-parameters.  Further, in order to gauge the performance of system, I’m planning to use several datasets.

Firstly, I divided first dataset into three sub-sets (i.e. training, cross validation and testing).

Cross validating dataset was used to find optimum values of hyper-parameters of the system.  Also, I increased the training dataset size in each iteration and performance was measured using the cross validation dataset. The reason for doing this was to identify the optimum size of the training dataset.

Now my question is:

Do I need to do all the steps mentioned above for other dataset, or can I use the parameters (such as hyper-parameters of the learning system and training dataset size etc.) obtained above?

Comment: Why isn't the size of the training sample fixed?

Comment: Actually, a papers based on this system is currently in the “Submissions Needing Revision” state of a learning journal. One of reviewers has suggested, using incremental training batches in order to find the optimum training data set size.